# Saving Images to document directory

Tags: iphone, image, url

i am fetching around 1500 image url and want to store these images in the document directory of iphone at one go??
please suggest any approach to do it...

thanks

Comment: I seldom post my queries here....it was also advised to me earlier...I know it sounds absurd but please tell me how to accept?

Comment: Click the white checkmark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method to download all URLs and write into one file:

```
     - (BOOL) downloadFilefromCDN :(NSString*)filename {

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/getlinks.php"]]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

        NSError *err = nil;
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&err];
        if (err != nil) { return FALSE; } // Download error

        NSArray *searchPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[searchPath objectAtIndex:0]  stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",filename]];
    if ([data writeToFile:path atomically:YES] != FALSE) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE; // Error
    }

    }
```

You need to write a script that returns an answer including the 1400 links so you can write it into that file.

Method to download all images given by a NSArray* to document directory.

```
- (id) downloadFilefromCDN :(NSString*)filename {

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/%@",filename]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSError *err = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&err];
    if (err != nil) { return FALSE; }

    return data;

}

- (NSArray*) downloadFilesfromCDN :(NSArray*)filenames {

    NSMutableArray *mfiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    BOOL error = FALSE;

    for (NSString* filename in filenames) {
        NSArray *searchPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *path = [[searchPath objectAtIndex:0]  stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",filename]];
            id file = [self downloadFilefromCDN:filename];
            if ([file isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
        if ([(NSData*)file writeToFile:path atomically:YES] != FALSE) {
            [mfiles addObject:path];
        } else {
            error = TRUE; // Writing of file failed
        }
            } else {
                    error = TRUE; // Download failed
            }
    }

    if (error) { 
          // Handle error
    }

    [filenames release];

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:mfiles];
}
```

Note: You need to read the pure filenames into a NSArray. If you have different origins change

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/%@",filename]
```

to

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",filename]
```

and read the full paths (http://example.com/file1.png,http://example.com/file2.png) into a NSArray.

Done. Hope it will help.

*Sorry for so much editing :S*

Comment: It works but it takes a lot of time....one could simply use this   UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/images/logo.png"]]];

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. If you want to download the files and get a full list of them and read them into UIImages then is my method perfect. If you know all paths and only want to read them into UIImages yours is perfect.